# Deadlock issue in update statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a keylock deadlock issue in an update statement in SQL Server. I have a clustered index on the primary key and I am using them inside the where clause. I can say for sure that the 2 processes are not updating the same rows as the java code is written like that. They are trying to update different rows but still this deadlock is occurring. Both processes are owner mode of X and requesting for U lock as per the graph. I can share the other as well.

```
<deadlock-list>
<deadlock victim="process147029c28">
<process-list>
<process id="process147029c28" taskpriority="0" logused="1300" 
waitresource="KEY: 7:72057600641925120 (ef40b100fec4)" waittime="6363" 
ownerId="7750344" transactionname="implicit_transaction" 
lasttranstarted="2018-10-25T21:52:35.553" XDES="0x10006ad90" lockMode="U" 
schedulerid="3" kpid="17860" status="suspended" spid="67" sbid="0" ecid="0" 
priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-10-25T21:52:36.567" 
lastbatchcompleted="2018-10-25T21:52:36.540" lastattention="1900-01- 
01T00:00:00.540" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" 
hostname="USGURBHABISHT9" hostpid="0" loginname="bharat" 
isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7750344" currentdb="7" 
lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 datetime2,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 varchar(8000),@P4 
varchar(8000),@P5 nvarchar(4000),@P6 nvarchar(4000),@P7 datetime2,@P8 
nvarchar(4000),@P9 varchar(8000),@P10 nvarchar(4000),@P11 
varchar(8000),@P12 bigint,@P13 varchar(8000),@P14 varchar(8000),@P15 
nvarchar(4000),@P16 varchar(8000),@P17 datetime2,@P18 nvarchar(4000),@P19 
nvarchar(4000),@P20 nvarchar(4000),@P21 varchar(8000),@P22 
nvarchar(4000),@P23 nvarchar(4000),@P24 nvarchar(4000),@P25 
nvarchar(4000),@P26 nvarchar(4000),@P27 nvarchar(4000),@P28 bigint,@P29 
nvarchar(4000),@P30 nvarchar(4000),@P31 nvarchar(4000),@P32 
nvarchar(4000),@P33 nvarchar(4000),@P34 nvarchar(4000))Update 
IN_R_AU_MEM_ELIG_DTL set APPROVAL_CODE = @P0, ARCHIVE_DT = @P1, 
CASE_NUMBER = @P2, CATEGORY_CODE = @P3, CG_STATUS_CODE = @P4, CLOSE_DATE = 
@P5, CLOSURE_CODE = @P6, CREATE_DT = @P7, CREATE_USER_ID = @P8, 
DELETE_INDICATOR = @P9, ELIGIBILITY_SEQUENCE_NUMBER = @P10, 
ELIG_INCAR_FLAG = @P11, HISTORY_SEQ = @P12, INCARCERATION_CODE = @P13, 
INCARCERATION_DISCHARGE_DATE =    </inputbuf>
</process>
<process id="process13e98b088" taskpriority="0" logused="1992" 
waitresource="KEY: 7:72057600641925120 (f128991fbbbb)" waittime="6349" 
ownerId="7751290" transactionname="implicit_transaction" 
lasttranstarted="2018-10-25T21:52:35.803" XDES="0x12f960d90" lockMode="U" 
schedulerid="3" kpid="6176" status="suspended" spid="66" sbid="0" ecid="0" 
priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-10-25T21:52:36.610" 
lastbatchcompleted="2018-10-25T21:52:36.603" lastattention="1900-01- 
01T00:00:00.603" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" 
hostname="USGURBHABISHT9" hostpid="0" loginname="bharat" 
isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="7751290" currentdb="7" 
lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128058">
<inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 datetime2,@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 varchar(8000),@P4 
varchar(8000),@P5 nvarchar(4000),@P6 nvarchar(4000),@P7 datetime2,@P8 
nvarchar(4000),@P9 varchar(8000),@P10 nvarchar(4000),@P11 
varchar(8000),@P12 bigint,@P13 varchar(8000),@P14 varchar(8000),@P15 
nvarchar(4000),@P16 varchar(8000),@P17 datetime2,@P18 nvarchar(4000),@P19 
nvarchar(4000),@P20 nvarchar(4000),@P21 varchar(8000),@P22 
nvarchar(4000),@P23 nvarchar(4000),@P24 nvarchar(4000),@P25 
nvarchar(4000),@P26 nvarchar(4000),@P27 nvarchar(4000),@P28 bigint,@P29 
nvarchar(4000),@P30 nvarchar(4000),@P31 nvarchar(4000),@P32 
nvarchar(4000),@P33 nvarchar(4000),@P34 nvarchar(4000))Update 
IN_R_AU_MEM_ELIG_DTL set APPROVAL_CODE = @P0, ARCHIVE_DT = @P1, 
CASE_NUMBER = @P2, CATEGORY_CODE = @P3, CG_STATUS_CODE = @P4, CLOSE_DATE = 
@P5, CLOSURE_CODE = @P6, CREATE_DT = @P7, CREATE_USER_ID = @P8, 
DELETE_INDICATOR = @P9, ELIGIBILITY_SEQUENCE_NUMBER = @P10, 
ELIG_INCAR_FLAG = @P11, HISTORY_SEQ = @P12, INCARCERATION_CODE = @P13, 
INCARCERATION_DISCHARGE_DATE =    </inputbuf>
</process>
</process-list>
<resource-list>
<keylock hobtid="72057600641925120" dbid="7" 
objectname="IEWP_EE.dbo.IN_R_AU_MEM_ELIG_DTL" 
indexname="IN_R_AU_MEM_ELIG_DTL_PK" id="lock104f34d00" mode="X" 
associatedObjectId="72057600641925120">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process13e98b088" mode="X"/>
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process147029c28" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
</waiter-list>
</keylock>
<keylock hobtid="72057600641925120" dbid="7" 
objectname="IEWP_EE.dbo.IN_R_AU_MEM_ELIG_DTL" 
indexname="IN_R_AU_MEM_ELIG_DTL_PK" id="lock12ac42100" mode="X" 
associatedObjectId="72057600641925120">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process147029c28" mode="X"/>
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process13e98b088" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
</waiter-list>
</keylock>
</resource-list>
</deadlock>
</deadlock-list>


Update statement:

Update table_name updating all the columns even the primary key
where 1=1  
AND PERSON_NUMBER = '7769999750768'
AND TYPE_CASE_CODE = '550'  
AND START_DATE = '20180901' 
AND INCARCERATION_ADMIT_DATE = '00000000' 
AND OSS_AMOUNT = '000'
AND AID_CATEGORY = '50' 

Columns used in the where clause are the composite primary key.
And two update queries deadlocking  are having different primary key values.
So how it can have a lock on primary key?
```

table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IN_R_AU_MEM_ELIG_DTL](
[CREATE_USER_ID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[CREATE_DT] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UNIQUE_TRANS_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[HISTORY_SEQ] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[RECORD_TYPE] [varchar](1) NULL,
[SUB_RECORD_TYPE] [varchar](1) NULL,
[RECORD_SEQUENCE] [varchar](9) NULL,
[PERSON_NUMBER] [varchar](13) NOT NULL,
[PERSON_SEQUENCE] [varchar](8) NULL,
[ELIGIBILITY_SEQUENCE_NUMBER] [varchar](5) NULL,
[CASE_NUMBER] [varchar](13) NULL,
[CATEGORY_CODE] [varchar](2) NULL,
[TYPE_CASE_CODE] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
[START_DATE] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[CLOSE_DATE] [varchar](8) NULL,
[APPROVAL_CODE] [varchar](3) NULL,
[CLOSURE_CODE] [varchar](3) NULL,
[DELETE_INDICATOR] [varchar](1) NULL,
[INCARCERATION_CODE] [varchar](1) NULL,
[INCARCERATION_ADMIT_DATE] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[INCARCERATION_DISCHARGE_DATE] [varchar](8) NULL,
[INCARCERATION_ELIG_FLAG] [varchar](1) NULL,
[RENEWAL_DATE] [varchar](8) NULL,
[RENEWAL_CODE] [varchar](2) NULL,
[PRE_RELEASE_DATE] [varchar](8) NULL,
[LOCATION_CODE] [varchar](4) NULL,
[MONEY_CODE] [varchar](1) NULL,
[OSS_AMOUNT] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[AID_CATEGORY] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[CG_STATUS_CODE] [varchar](5) NULL,
[MMIS_SND_PERSON_SEQ_NUM] [varchar](15) NULL,
[PROCESS_SW] [varchar](1) NULL,
[ELIG_INCAR_FLAG] [varchar](1) NULL,
[ARCHIVE_DT] [datetime] NULL,
[ROWID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
[MMIS_SND_DT] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [IN_R_AU_MEM_ELIG_DTL_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[INCARCERATION_ADMIT_DATE] ASC,
[AID_CATEGORY] ASC,
[OSS_AMOUNT] ASC,
[PERSON_NUMBER] ASC,
[START_DATE] ASC,
[TYPE_CASE_CODE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Please include the queries, the deadlock .xdl, and whether the statements are part of a larger transaction (this is typically the cause for two identical statements deadlocking).

Comment: Do you have a small repro that you can post?  Queries, table structures, etc.  That would be very helpful to have so that we can see more of what's going on. Please see [ask] and [mcve] for further guidance.

Comment: Deadlock graph xml is like above.

Comment: after much of searching i have come to the conclusion that it's deadlocking even when we are updating different primary keys  because they are like key hashes.My question would be howto solve this deadlock

Comment: hey waiting for precious answers!!! :)

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Can you please share your thoughts on this one.

Comment: There isn't enough info in the deadlock graph to determine why the deadlock happens. They are both locking on the same index, and different rows, sure, but there is some info missing. What do the plans for these update queries look like? Seeks, scans, key lookups? Do they try to lock a row or do they escalate to table/page? Can you get the deadlock to happen in two sessions in SSMS? I doubt it, because there is likely more to how the Java application is controlling things. Are you using any kind of transaction management in Java? Are there are other statements involved in these transactions?

Comment: Yes i am using a simple java transaction api for managing my transactions. UPDATE statement gets scan on clustered index

Comment: Yes other statements are also involved in these transaction but they are related to other tables. All the selects on this particular table have been with(nolock). So now only updates in multithreaded environment is causing issues.

Comment: If you have a transaction surrounding an update to table x, then table y, and another transaction that updates table y and then table x, this is a problem. If you have a transaction surrounding 400 statements and it takes 5 minutes, it doesn't matter how many other tables those statements touch, this is a problem. Make sure your transactions are short and sweet, process tables in the same order, and quite frankly I wouldn't be implementing transaction management in application code unless it also managed isolated/non-idempotent operations outside of the database.

Comment: All the transactions are having the same order. I think the problem is the lock on key hashes. Can you help me with that.